# How to use php error_log when running phpmailer with rabbitmq

Tags: php, rabbitmq, phpmailer

In order for my PHP program to send emails in the background, I have used rabbitmq with phpmailer. The email is working great most of the time. But I cannot figure out how to send the error message to a log file.

In normal PHP code, I'm using the error_log function and I will view the error log in folder /var/log/nginx/error.log

But here, I don't know where the log message goes. Helps is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I create my own log file with this function

```
function errorLog($msg) {
   $now = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
   $myfile = fopen("phpmail_log.txt", "a");
   fwrite($myfile, $now . ' ## ' . $msg . "\n\r");
   fclose($myfile);
}
```

I can call it from anywhere in my code as below

```
errorLog('send any debug info to log here');
```

Hope this can help others facing the same problem.